# Consumir webservice wsdl em java

Tags: java, web-service, wsdl

Preciso consumir um webservice wsdl mas não sei como faço para carregar um método e passar os parametros dentro desse webservice para que ele me retorne o valor desejado.

Este é o webservice:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" name="IadWSMediaParcialservice" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<message name="CalcularMediaParcial0Request">
<part name="dirConfigIni" type="xs:string"/>
<part name="GUID" type="xs:string"/>
<part name="idEmpresa" type="xs:int"/>
<part name="idGrupoEmpresa" type="xs:int"/>
<part name="idUsuario" type="xs:int"/>
<part name="idPeriodoLetivo" type="xs:int"/>
<part name="idCurso" type="xs:int"/>
<part name="idCiclo" type="xs:int"/>
<part name="idSerie" type="xs:int"/>
<part name="idFaseCalendario" type="xs:int"/>
<part name="idProfessor" type="xs:int"/>
<part name="idDisciplina" type="xs:int"/>
<part name="idTurma" type="xs:int"/>
</message>
<message name="CalcularMediaParcial0Response">
<part name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</message>
<portType name="IadWSMediaParcial">
<operation name="CalcularMediaParcial">
<input message="tns:CalcularMediaParcial0Request"/>
<output message="tns:CalcularMediaParcial0Response"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="IadWSMediaParcialbinding" type="tns:IadWSMediaParcial">
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="CalcularMediaParcial">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:adWSMediaParcialIntf-IadWSMediaParcial#CalcularMediaParcial" style="rpc"/>
<input message="tns:CalcularMediaParcial0Request">
<soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:adWSMediaParcialIntf-IadWSMediaParcial"/>
</input>
<output message="tns:CalcularMediaParcial0Response">
<soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:adWSMediaParcialIntf-IadWSMediaParcial"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="IadWSMediaParcialservice">
<port name="IadWSMediaParcialPort" binding="tns:IadWSMediaParcialbinding">
<soap:address location="http://adv-des-12/adWSMediaParcial.dll/soap/IadWSMediaParcial"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Criei a seguinte interface:

```
public interface DLL {

    public String CalcularMediaParcial(String caminho,
            String GUID, int idEmpresa, int idGrupoEmpresa, int idUsuario, int idPeriodoLetivo,
            int idCurso, int idCiclo, int idSerie, int idFaseCalendario, int idProfessor, int idDisciplina,
            int idTurma);

    public void LiberarRecursos();
}
```

Como faço para carregar webservice e chamar esse método CalcularMediaParcial?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o comando:

```
wsimport -d [caminho_destino_do_source] [arquivo_wsdl]
```

Nesse destino, as classes serão geradas, basta importar na sua IDE.

Comment: Este comando é linux?

Comment: esse utilitário vem junto com a jdk, pelo menos, na OpenJDK 8.

Comment: Blz, com as classes geradas conseguimos consumir o wsdl ?

Comment: vai criar um punhado de classes e junto vai criar uma interface do mesmo estilo a que você criou [link](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/)